# Is @EnableRedisRepositories unable to handle nested references?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-redis

I would like to use `@EnableRedisRepositories` in conjunction with a custom data type that includes a back reference and is sadly causing some serialization trouble. Below is the setup of my project:

###### A.java

```
public class A {
   @Id long id;
   @JsonManagedReference List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();

   public A(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

###### B.java

```
public class B {
   long id;
   @JsonBackReference A parent;

   public B(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

###### MyApplication.java

```
@EnableRedisRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

###### CacheRepository.java

```
public interface CacheRepository extends KeyValueRepository<A, Long> {}
```

###### MyService.java

```
[...]
   @Autowired CacheRepository cacheRepository;

   public void test() {
      A a = new A(1);

      B b1 = new B(1);
      B b2 = new B(2);
      a.bs.add(b1);
      a.bs.add(b2);

      cacheRepository.save(a); // fails with `StackOverflowError`
   }
```

##### Problems

1. Out of the box, this does not work and throws `StackOverflowError`
2. I have attempted several strategies, all to no avail, including:

- defining my own Redis template
- defining my own converters
- defining my own serializers
- annotating the list with `@JsonIgnore` but apparently all annotations are simply ignored

---

Can someone shed some light on how to make this work?